# Windows Forms: Resolution Issue

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-2.0, screen-resolution

I am C++ programmer, and I am working on a migration project where I need to convert C++ code to C# and I have little knowledge on C#. Also, Clients want the application in .net 2.0

Issue:

1. When the screen resolution changes to low resolution, the form is adding a scroll bar to show all the controls in the screen. But, Client wants without any scroll bar such that all the controls should be visible.
2. Font applied to the controls should fit to the control dimension even if we change the resolution to high or low.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have an example? what is adding a scroll bar?

Comment: @Sayse There are buttons, custom user controls in the form, everything will be messed up if I change the screen resolution.

Comment: That still doesn't explain scroll bars, normally controls tend to just get drawn out of range. What anchoring and docking is present

Answer (score 1):

Use containers to house your controls.  TableLayoutPanel would probably be a good choice.  Set the TableLayoutPanels DockStyle to Fill.  TableLayoutPanels only allow you to put one Control in each section, but Panels allow multiples so put a Panel in each section and set each Panels DockStyle to Fill.  Arrange your controls in the panels and set each controls Anchor or DockStyle properties to keep them in location.  Now, set your resolution to the lowest possible setting and build your form.  If you follow the above steps, when you raise the resolution everything will be in the same relative location with the same relative size.

Why it works:  Setting the tablelayoutpanels DockStyle to Fill makes it autosize with the parent form.  Setting each panels DockStyle makes it autosize with the TableLayoutPanels sections.  Anchoring/Docking controls inside the panels keeps the controls sizing and spacing relative to the panel.